# Is there a way to create a TS utility type which can hold anything but a certain type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have been wondering whether it is possible to define a type which would allow any value except (some arbitrary) type.

Let's take Date as an example. I would like to have a type called NonDate which would hold anything but date.

My best shot at this would be:

```
type NotDate<T = any> = T extends Date ? never : T;
```

From my experience, I know that this wouldn't work and would just evaluate to any, letting us do something like this:

```
// doesnt produce an error
const failure: NonDate = new Date()
```

I am aware that typescript doesn't support type substraction, nor does it seem to plan to implement it. However, I feel like I was lacking this feature many times while working with generics and was wondering whether someone has a solution/workaround for this. Many thanks.

Comment: You can use `Exclude` utility type. The Exclude type takes two type parameters, `T` and `U`, and creates a new type that represents all the properties of `T` except those that are also in `U`.

Comment: Follow the official doc
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers

Comment: Thank you, I do know about exclude, however in the example provided above, Exclude<any, Date> would produce the very same results (of evaluating to any)

Comment: There is no specific type that works this way (as you say, there are no subtraction types in TS); if you're okay using generics as a workaround, then you can make a generic type and associated helper function as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0YLrW) so that instead of `const foo: NonDate = ...` you write `const foo = nonDate(...)`.  Does that meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that actually answers it. I did not think about doing this as a solution. Thank you a lot for helping.